# What does "run" mean here?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

A scene from the movie *Warrior*:

> Paddy: Have a heart, Brendan.
>
> Brendan: You listen to me. You take your "have a heart" bullshit and you **run it down the road**. Yeah, **run it out** with someone that doesn't know you like I do.

Are **run it down the road** and **run it out** phrasal verbs here? I can't find dictionary entries of these two phrasal verbs that fit this context. It appears Brendan is saying: "You take your bullshit elsewhere." But what does **run** mean here exactly? I know **run** is one of the words with the most meanings in the English language. But I have looked through the Oxford Dictionaries and Merriam Webster, but can't be sure which meaning this usage is.

Answer (score 1):

This is very idiomatic usage, I'm not surprised that you don't find examples in the dictionary; I can't claim that I've ever heard either phrase. I think you're correct in considering them to be phrasal verbs.

Your analysis of the phrases is plausible.

Phrases I do hear in business contexts:

> Let's run that idea past XXX

Meaning to seek XXX's opinion

> Let's run that up the flagpole,

Meaning canvas the opinions of a wider community. That example is a shorter version of the complete phrase:

> Let's run that up the flagpole, see whether anyone salutes

I'm then reading

> run it out with someone that doesn't know you like I do

to mean: "take the idea to someone who will believe it"

and it is being used as a emphasis for the previous phrase

> Take "Have a heart" somewhere else far away
>
> Take it to someone who might believe it

Comment: +1 Thank you for the answer. In your second example, what do you mean by "optionally with"?

Comment: I've expanded the answer, hope it's clear now.